# Using Freddy to deserialize a list of strings

Tags: json, swift

I'm experimenting with Freddy in Swift:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/Freddy

And am trying to deserialize a list of strings.  My Json looks something like this:

```
{
    "types": ["A", "B", "C"],
}
```

Here's the swift code:

```
import Freddy

struct Config {
    let types: [JSON]
}
extension Config: JSONDecodable {
    public init(json: JSON) throws {
        types = try json.getArray(at: "types")
    }
}
```

This all seems to load correctly, but I'm not able to get the list of strings as an actual array of strings - they are an array of type JSON.  What do I do from here to map these into strings?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Freddy objects are of type JSON - it works a bit like with SwiftyJSON.

Freddy has a getter named `decodedArray()` that will do what you need.

Example:

```
struct Config {
    let types: [String]
}

extension Config: JSONDecodable {
    public init(json: JSON) throws {
        types = try json.decodedArray(at: "types", type: String.self)
    }
}

// instances
let json = try! JSON(data: data)
let c = try! Config(json: json)

//tests
print(c.types)
print(type(of: c.types))
```

Prints:

`["A", "B", "C"]`
`Array<String>`

---

If you prefer keeping your "types" an array of JSON instead of an array of String, then use your original code and extract the strings with Freddy's `getString()` getter and `flatMap`:

```
// here .types is [JSON]
let strings = c.types.flatMap { try? $0.getString() }
```